# Should we take only positive root i.e. -y or both the roots + or -y?

Tags: roots, square-numbers, gre-exam

As in gre, square root symbol means principal square root, what should be the answer in this case? Should we take only positive root i.e., $-y$ or both the roots $+$ or $-y$?

If $y < 0$, $\sqrt{-y|y|} =$ ?

A : $y$

B : $1$

C : $-1$

D : $-y$

E : $\pm y$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recall that the absolute value is defined by
$$
|x| = \begin{cases} x \text{ if } x\geq 0,\\ -x\text{ if } x<0. \end{cases}
$$
In other words: when the number is positive, the absolute value is the same number; when the number is negative, you have tu change the sign of the number, that is why you have to add a minus. In the problem, you have to do the following substitution,
$$
−y|y|=(−y)(−y)=(−y)^2
$$
because, since $y$ is negative, the absolute value $|y|$ is precisely $-y$.

Thus, we have to find the square root of $(−y)^2$, i.e., a positive nuber whose square is $(−y)^2$. But this is precisely $−y$, since $y<0$. Hence, the answer is $D$.

Comment: I can't understand why this answer, the only one correct/complete/ explained, was downvoted. Perhaps I'm missing something, but in the meantime I shall upvote it.

Comment: Recall that the absolute value is defined by 
$$
|x| = \begin{cases}
x \text{ if } x\geq 0,\\
-x\text{ if } x<0.
\end{cases}
$$
In other words: when the number is positive, the absolute value is the same number; when the number is negative, you have tu change the sign of the number, that is why you have to add a minus.

What I did in $-y|y| = (-y)^{2}$ was the following substitution:
$$
-y|y| = (-y) (-y) = (-y)^{2}
$$
because, since $y$ is negative, the absolute value $|y|$ is precisely $-y$.

Comment: I encourage anyone to upvote this answer since it indeed is better than the one I provided. Also @LaloVelasco could you edit the answer so to include the text of your comment here? That way the answer perhaps would be better and my vote would be ulocked so I could upvote this answer so to move it up on the thread.

Comment: Thanks for your encouraging. I just edited my old answer.

Comment: @LaloVelasco thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

No, $\sqrt{a}$ is a strictly defined **single number**, defined as

> Given a real number $a$, the number $\sqrt{x}$ is the **non-negative** solution to the equation $x^2=a$

So, for example, $\sqrt9$ does **not** equal "plus or minus $3$", it equals $3$. It is true that the equation $x^2=9$ has *two* real solutions, $+$ and $-3$, but the task in front of you isn't asking about that.

Comment: A is the answer?

Comment: @Saurabh I don't know, do you think that $y$ is the non-negative solution to the equation $x^2=\sqrt{-y|y|}$?

Comment: yes i think so..because square always give positive number, we can not take negative numbers squares.

Comment: @Saurabh That's true, but is $y$ a **non-negative** solution?

Comment: Don't forget to remember the initial conditions while thinking about the question above.

Comment: when y = -2, after solving getting +2, is this mean any negative number will be positive after taking square... then A (Y) is the answer.

Comment: @Saurabh No, $A$ is not the answer. Because $y$ is **not** the ***non-negative** solution to your equation. If $y=-2$, then you need to find $\sqrt{4}$, and $-2$ is **not** equal to $\sqrt{4}$. Read my answer again to see why.

Comment: The answer is +2 however with $y=-2$ we express $+2$ as $-y=-(-2)=+2$

Comment: @ahra Is this a comment to me or to OP?

Comment: @5xum to the OP just to provide additional clarification.